# Full Text Catalog Search not returning any results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

The stored procedure below contains a semantickeyphrasetable function call:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_JobsSemanticSearch 'top it officer', 193, 'SA1Web', 500, '6/11/2018'
```

That should return JobDOTTitle column containing ‘Top IT Officer’ toward the very top (but is not even included in the whole list).

The call below should return 2 entries (for Document_Key = 7 and (keyphrase = ‘top” or keyphrase = ‘officer’)) for the following reasons:

1. Dbo.Job is part of the FULL TEXT CATALOG named SA_JOB_FT_CAT
2. The JobDotTitle column is specified the SA_JOB_FT_CAT with a “Statistical Semantics” flag enabled
3. Document_Key (from semantickeyphrasetable) referrers to EriJobId from dbo.Job
4. EriJobId = 7 refers to the job named  “Top IT Officer” from dbo.Job table

Code:

```
select * 
from semantickeyphrasetable([dbo].[Job], ([JobDotTitle])) as JK 
where JK.[Document_Key] = 7
```

This returns nothing though....

I've tried running incremental population, I did a full population. Can't figure out why this isn't working. This is for SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.  Rebuild of full text catalog[image]